# Question on proving vectors

Tags: vectors

How do you prove $|p+q|=|p-q|$ ?This  question are getting me nervous on the whole vectors chapter and how do you use the properties on this one?or maybe you don't need to use one(?)

Comment: In general this is not true. What do we know about $p$ and $q$?

Comment: Squaring gives $p\cdot p+q\cdot q + 2p\cdot q = p\cdot p+q\cdot q - 2p\cdot q$, so the required result is equivalent to the presumably unstated assumption $p\cdot q=0$ (i.e. $p$ is orthogonal to $q$).

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ and $q$ are vectors in the plane, then it might be helpful to think about this geometrically. If you draw the vectors $p$ and $q$ starting from the origin, then draw another copy of $p$ starting from $q$, and $q$ starting from $p$, the result is a parallelogram. The diagonals of the parallelogram are the vectors $p+q$ and $p-q$, and these diagonals have the same length precisely when the parallelogram is a rectangle, i.e. when $p$ and $q$ are perpendicular.